Unable to Scroll Properly Using Selenium Script in the mobile device - Appium
I am using the script:
Dimension ScreenSize = driver.manage().window().getSize();
// System.out.println(ScreenSize);
// Current device size (720, 1465) //

//Finding Starting point/mid of the screen size
int Xaxis = ScreenSize.getWidth() / 2;
int Yaxis = ScreenSize.getHeight() / 2;
    
//Finding End Point of the finger swipe
//In this we assumpting the size of 1000 and diving in 4 sides. So, 250 1 4th of the screen size
int Xend = Xaxis;
int Yend = (int) (ScreenSize.getHeight() * 0.25);
    
//Adding the pointer then using to create a Sequence
PointerInput Touch = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "Touch");
    
//Adding the Sequence of Action
Sequence Action = new Sequence(Touch, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Action.addAction(Touch.createPointerMove(Duration.ZERO, PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), Xaxis, Yaxis))
        .addAction(Touch.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()))
        .addAction(new Pause(Touch, Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
        .addAction(Touch.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(1000), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), Xend, Yend))
        .addAction(Touch.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));

    try {
        driver.perform(Collections.singletonList(Action));
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Pause between scrolls
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Handle or log the exception as needed
    }
}
    
Thread.sleep(3000); // Wait at the end

To Scroll until it exist from the loop but the problem I am facing is during the scrolling, it clicking on the element and scrolling on that element page. And I am unable to understand what this happening !
Explored, changed script, add the Thread.sleep among many other things with no results.
